# Spring Security Oauth2 Resource Owner Password flow: When I send a REST request, my user detail service always gets the client id instead of username

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

So I'm trying to send a request to my oauth server (with no headers): **grant_type=password&username=blah&password=blah&client_id=blahblah.**

I have 2 authentication-manager (one for the client and another for the user validation). The problem is, none of my authentication managers are being passing the username to verify. In both cases, they are being called with the client_id. What I want is one to verify the client and the other to verify the user.

My bean configuration is this:

```
 <http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"  authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />

    <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />  

    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>


<!-- The OAuth2 protected resources are separated out into their own block so we can deal with authorization and error handling 
    separately. This isn't mandatory, but it makes it easier to control the behaviour. -->
<http pattern="/api/**" create-session="stateless" entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/api" access="ROLE_USER,SCOPE_READ" />

    <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>


<authentication-manager  alias="authenticationManager"  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
    <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailService">
        <sec:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />
    </sec:authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>


<beans:bean id="customUserDetailService" class="com.cointraders.api.securities.UserDetailsServiceImpl" />


<beans:bean id="clientDetails" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.JdbcClientDetailsService">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:list>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter" />
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
        </beans:list>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>

<oauth:authorization-server client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices">
    <oauth:refresh-token />
    <oauth:password authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager"  />
</oauth:authorization-server>


<oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter" resource-id="api" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

<sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true">
    <sec:expression-handler ref="oauthExpressionHandler" />
</sec:global-method-security>

<oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler" />

<oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />

<beans:bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <beans:property name="realmName" value="api/" />
</beans:bean>



<beans:bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
</beans:bean>


<beans:bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.JdbcTokenStore">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</beans:bean>


<beans:bean id="tokenServices" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
    <beans:property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
    <beans:property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
    <beans:property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="clientDetailsUserService" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />

<beans:bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <beans:property name="realmName" value="api" />
</beans:bean>
```

This is my Web.XML

```
    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextAttribute</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.spring</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/*.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

My User Detail Service Class

```
 public class UserDetailsServiceImpl extends PersonServiceImpl implements
    UserDetailsService {

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    UserDetails details = null;
    Specification<Person> specs = Specifications.where(PersonSpecification.equalsUserName(username));
    Person person = this.personRepository.findOne(specs);
    if(person!=null)
    {   
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        authorities.add(new   SimpleGrantedAuthority(person.getRole().getRole().name()));
        details = new User(person.getUserName(), person.getPassword(), person.getActive(), false, false, false, authorities);
    }
    return details;
 }

 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `<authorization-server/>` you haven't set the `AuthenticationManager` in the `<password/>` grant type (so it is using the default bean name "authenticationManager" which you have mapped to the client credentials).

An additional problem is that you use `<authentication-manager/>` twice without giving an explicit "id=" for either, which actually has the effect of defining only one `AuthenticationManager` since the second one overrides the first (they both have the same id). Try using "id=" instead of "alias=".

You really need to send the client credentials in a header if you can (but you probably know that).

Comment: Ok so I added the user detail service to my <authorization-server /> under password. Here's the snippet->**
  <oauth:password authentication-manager-ref="userAuthenticationManager"  />**. Here's a print screen when I have everything in the request body and what I get from debugging my user details service. [link](http://tinypic.com/r/2mx1g29/8) & [link](http://tinypic.com/r/2wn0d45/8). I am not sure why do I need to include the client id in the header (along with the grant type). When I have them in the header, error "An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext"

Comment: Also, when I remove both the client_id and grant_type from the request body to the header, I get this error [link](http://tinypic.com/r/110asl0/8) and it doesn't even hit any one of my authentication-manager.

Comment: OK, so you didn't (know that). Client authentication is normally done with HTTP Basic and you even have that configured, so I thought you might have realized. Basic authentication is done with the Authorization header (look it up). The grant_type and user credentials (unfortunately) have to be in the body. Your configuration is now in good shape, so you just need to figure out how to send a valid token request.

Comment: I updated the request to include the basic authentication, see [link](http://tinypic.com/r/11ajpnb/8) . However, when I still make the request, my user detail service is still getting the client_id as the username parameter. I've updated my first post with the new beans configuration and added my web.xml as well. Thanks

Comment: Here's an image of the user details service parameter "username" and it's value. At no time you see "user" value in the username [link](http://tinypic.com/r/2gxjivp/8). Note see arrow in the upper right hand.

Comment: The configuration of your token endpoint security looks fine now. I can't see enough of the stack to see where your `UserDetailsService` is being called from. It might help to know that. And maybe to see some logs (with security at DEBUG) so we can see whether the client has authenticated and what filters are firing.

Comment: Well looking at the stack trace, it seems the basic authentication is calling the wrong user details services; which is the clientDetailsUserService (configured under authenticationManager) and not the customUserDetailService (configured under userAuthenticationManager). Again, the "authenticationManager" is used for client authentication and the "userAuthenticationManager" is used for user authentication.

Comment: With both authentication managers, I was having problem. The <http> element requires the authentication-manager to have alias or it won't find it with only id defined. So I was having the same issue as before but, I use only 1 authentication-manager with multiple authentication-providers. See first post (edited) for solution. Thanks